# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() precision?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The documentation says we can specify a precision from 0 (second) to 9 (nanosecond)

However it seems to default to milliseconds whatever I do...

```
SELECT 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS CT0a
  ,to_varchar(CT0a, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9') AS CT0b
  ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1) AS CT1a
  ,to_varchar(CT1a, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9') AS CT1b
  ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(9) AS CT9a
  ,to_varchar(CT9a, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9') AS CT9b
  ;
```

Seems to return the same thing if I display it with enough decimals, which is invariably milliseconds...

```
CT0A 2020-04-08 23:37:56.667 +0000  
CT0B 2020-04-08 23:37:56.667000000  
CT1A 2020-04-08 23:37:56.600 +0000  
CT1B 2020-04-08 23:37:56.667000000  
CT9A 2020-04-08 23:37:56.667 +0000  
CT9B 2020-04-08 23:37:56.667000000
```

The CT0a, CT1a and CT2a are displayed with the appropriate number of decimals but CT0b, CT1b and CT9b all display the exact same time up to 3 decimals...

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

While the Snowflake timestamp data type supports precision up to 9 digits, the current_timestamp function does not. Anything beyond milliseconds would be false precision for the clock, so it's not reported.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_timestamp.html

> Valid values range from 0 - 9. However, most platforms do not support
>   true nanosecond precision; the precision that you get might be less
>   than the precision you specify. In practice, precision is usually
>   approximately milliseconds (3 digits) at most.

If you don't specify the output format, Snowflake will display with three decimal places for seconds, even if the internal precision is higher:

```
select to_timestamp(15863566077839811234, 9); -- Seconds has 9 digit precision, but displays 3
select to_varchar(to_timestamp(15863566077839811234, 9), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9'); -- Displays all 9 digit precision
```

Comment: Yes, but when I ask for second precision, I still get milliseconds? That has nothing to do with the underlying platform?

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1) AS CT1a, to_varchar(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9'); returns 2020-04-08 07:24:49.352000000... Why .352???

Comment: If you don't specify the formatting, Snowflake displays three decimal places for the seconds even if the precision is set internally different. For example: select to_timestamp(15863566077839811234, 9); -- Seconds has 9 digit precision, but displays 3
select to_varchar(to_timestamp(15863566077839811234, 9), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF9'); -- Displays all 9 digit precision. (Added this example to the answer for ease of reading).

Comment: This is not quite my question. If I request a timestamp to tenth of a second precision, I do not expect to receive hundredth and milliseconds.
So in my earlier example, I would expect to receive 2020-04-08 07:24:49.300000000 (or 2020-04-08 07:24:49.400000000) and then on display I should get 2020-04-08 07:24:49.300. But that is not what I observe